# How do I print the nth argument of a script, when n isn't known until runtime?

Tags: bash, shell-script, echo

I am writing a shell script and I need to print the nth argument of the script.

For example,
suppose we have `n=3` and our script is run with enough arguments.
Now I need to print the `n`th argument, i.e. `$3`.

But if `n=2`, we would print argument `$2`.

I don't want to use `if` statements. I wanted to do something like

```
echo $($n)
```

but the above doesn't work the way I need it to.

Comment: It looks like you mixed up _command substition_, `$()`, with _parameter expansion_, `${}`.  So you're starting from the wrong section in the manual...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By chronological order, in various shells:

- csh (late 70s): `$argv[$n]` (also works in zsh since 1991 and fish since 2005)
- zsh (1991): `$argv[n]` / `$@[n]` / `$*[n]` (the last too also supported by yash but only with extra braces: `${@[n]}` / `${*[n]}`)
- rc (early 90s): `$$n` / `$*($n)` (also works in es, akanga)
- ksh93 (1993): `${@:n:1}`, `${*:n:1}` (also supported by bash since 1996; zsh also [since 2010](https://zsh.org/workers/28418), though you need `${@:$n:1}` or `${@: n:1}` there to avoid conflict with csh-style modifiers and see [there](https://zsh.org/workers/49819) about the `"$*"` case)
- bash (1996): `${!n}`
- zsh ([1999](https://zsh.org/workers/5200)): `${(P)n}`.

Remember that in ksh93/bash/yash, you need to quote parameter expansions in list contexts at least, and csh can hardly be used to write reliable code.

In `bash`, there's a difference between `"${!n}"` and `"${@:n:1}"` in list context when the n<sup>th</sup> positional parameter is not set in that the latter then expands to no argument at all whilst the former expands to one empty element.

In Bourne-like shells (but not the Bourne shell where that won't work for indices past the 9th), and with standard POSIX sh syntax, you can also do:

```
eval "nth=\${$n}"
```

There will also be differences in behaviour among all those if `$n` does not contain the canonical decimal representation of an integer number strictly greater than 0. If you can't guarantee that will be the case, using most of those (not just the `eval` one) would introduce an arbitrary command execution vulnerability (the only exceptions being with `rc` and maybe `csh` above).

Also remember that except in `zsh` (with `echo -E - $argv[n]`), `yash` (with `ECHO_STYLE=raw echo "${*[$n]}"`) and `fish` (with `echo -- $argv[$n]`), [`echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data, use `printf '%s\n' ...` instead](/q/65803)).

Answer (score 17):

The arguments you pass to a script are stored in the `@` array, so the simple way to do what you want is to take an [array slice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336245/1081936), starting at position `n` and having a length of 1:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=3
echo "Argument $n: ${@:n:1}"
```

If you run this with a few arguments, you get:

```
$ foo.sh a b c d e f
Argument 3: c
```

---

The other alternative, and what you were originally asking for, is called "indirect expansion":

```
#!/bin/bash

n=3
echo "Argument $n: ${!n}"
```

Running this:

```
$ foo.sh a b c d e f
Argument 3: c
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use variable indirection:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
n=3
echo "${!n}"
```

Answer (score 5):

Simple portable shell (no bash dependency) solution (modulo potential badness of the `echo` command; it could be replaced with `printf`):

```
print_nth () {
    shift "$1"
    echo "$1"
}
```

Then do:

```
print_nth "$n" "$@"
```

Comment: I like the way that putting the `n` argument first neatly converts 0-based indexing into 1-based!

Comment: @TobySpeight: Note that if anyone wants a different indexing convention, it's easy to do the shell arithmetic on `$1` to adjust it.